# MySQL Group By to find unique combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, sum

Firstly apologies for the vague title, I really don't know how to phrase it and I think that's why I haven't been able to find a solution already.

Using a modified install of OSCommerce, I'm trying to find unique combinations of ordered product options/attributes in a table for a custom report. Each option/attribute of a product is stored in a row.  A product can (and does) have more than one option/attribute.

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT
sum(op.products_quantity) AS attrCnt,
opa.products_options AS prodOption,
opa.products_options_values AS prodOptionValue
FROM
store_orders_products_attributes opa
LEFT JOIN store_orders o ON o.orders_id = opa.orders_id
LEFT JOIN store_orders_products op ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
WHERE
o.customers_id = '99999'
AND (o.date_purchased BETWEEN CAST('2017-01-03' AS DATE)
AND CAST('2017-02-01' AS DATE))
AND op.products_id = 88888
GROUP BY
opa.products_options_values
ORDER BY
opa.products_options,
opa.products_options_values
```

Which returns:

```
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
| attrCnt |  prodOption   | prodOptionValue |
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
|       6 | Select Colour | Blue            |
|       1 | Select Colour | Yellow          |
|       1 | Select Size   | L               |
|       2 | Select Size   | M               |
|       4 | Select Size   | S               |
+---------+---------------+-----------------+
```

The total products ordered for that period was 7, 1 Large, 2 Medium, 4 Small, - 6 Blue, 1 Yellow.  From that I can't tell if the L (Large) was blue or yellow etc.

The result I would like is something like below (whether it's L - Blue or Blue - L doesn't matter):

```
+---------+-----------------+
| attrCnt | prodOptionCombo |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | L - Blue        |
|       2 | M - Blue        |
|       3 | S - Blue        |
|       1 | S - Yellow      |
+---------+-----------------+
```

The table containing this information is store_orders_products_attributes:

products_options column could contain any classification text grouping (free text), such as Select Flavour, Select xyz etc, so it wont always be Colour/Size

It's not always two options per product either, it could be 0, 1 or 12 or more.

```
+-------------------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| orders_products_attributes_id | orders_id | orders_products_id | products_options | products_options_values |
+-------------------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
|                          1420 |       596 |               2626 | Select Colour    | Blue                    |
|                          1421 |       596 |               2626 | Select Size      | M                       |
|                          1438 |       600 |               2656 | Select Colour    | Blue                    |
|                          1439 |       600 |               2656 | Select Size      | M                       |
|                          1445 |       601 |               2668 | Select Colour    | Blue                    |
|                          1446 |       601 |               2668 | Select Size      | S                       |
|                          1447 |       602 |               2671 | Select Colour    | Yellow                  |
|                          1448 |       602 |               2671 | Select Size      | S                       |
|                          1464 |       611 |               2705 | Select Colour    | Blue                    |
|                          1465 |       611 |               2705 | Select Size      | S                       |
|                          1502 |       634 |               2791 | Select Colour    | Blue                    |
|                          1503 |       634 |               2791 | Select Size      | L                       |
    +-------------------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

store_orders_products table contains:

```
+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| orders_products_id | orders_id | products_id | products_model | products_name | products_quantity |
+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
|               2626 |       596 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 1 |
|               2656 |       600 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 1 |
|               2668 |       601 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 1 |
|               2671 |       602 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 1 |
|               2705 |       611 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 2 |
|               2791 |       634 |       88888 | Code123        | Gloves        |                 1 |
+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't figure out why they're storing two different attributes (color and size) in the same column(products_options_values), isn't this a conception problem ?

Comment: @mounaim You'd have to speak with Harald Ponce de Leon original creator of OSCommerce.  The information is stored in a similar way before ordering against products so they save it in a similar way after ordering.  Options can have different pricing/weight applied +/- money kg etc.

Order display is 
Product Name
-- Select Colour = Blue
-- Select Size = L

As a result of storing data in that way.

Comment: @mounaim also the amount of options is unlimited, if size, colour, xyz etc were to have their own columns there could be 100's of columns

Answer (score 0):

To get started, use this subquery instead of the raw table:

```
(
select a1.orders_id,
       a1.products_options_values as sizeval, 
       a2.products_options_values as colourval
from store_orders_products_attributes a1
inner join store_orders_products_attributes a2
  on a1.orders_id = a2.orders_id
where a1.products_options = 'Size'
and a2.products_options = 'Colour' --  Yay, another brit
) x1
```

Comment: Great idea, however and sorry I should have said in initial post, products_options could contain any classification that the client has entered, Select Flavour, Select Capacity etc